# Difference and examples of esc_attr__() and esc_attr_e()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I want to know what is the difference between these functions.

> esc_attr__() and esc_attr_e()

What would be an example of use, when they are recommened to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in their source code. If you have a look in the source code of [`esc_attr__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr__/#source) we'll have this-

```
function esc_attr__( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return esc_attr( translate( $text, $domain ) );
}
```

And if we go for the source code of [`esc_attr_e`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_e/#source) we'll get this below code block-

```
function esc_attr_e( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    echo esc_attr( translate( $text, $domain ) );
}
```

Now you can clearly see the difference. [`esc_attr__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr__/#source) is returning the value and [`esc_attr_e`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_e/#source) is echoing the value.

**[`esc_attr__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr__/#source) Use Case Example:**

Now if you just want put the translated value of an attribute to some variable you have to use [`esc_attr__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr__/#source). See below example-

```
$translated_value = esc_attr__( 'Your Text', 'your_text_domain' );
<input title="<?php echo $translated_value ?>" type="submit" value="submit" >
```

Look we are putting the value to `$translated_value` variable first and then we are echoing it in `input` field's `title` attribute.

**[`esc_attr_e`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_e/#source) Use Case Example:**

Well, if you need to `echo` the attribute directly after translation then you should use [`esc_attr_e`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_e/#source). Example given below-

```
<input title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Read More', 'your_text_domain' ) ?>" type="submit" value="submit" >
```

Hope this above helps.